# ggplot - error data must be a data frame

Tags: raster, r, data-frame, ggplot

[image]

[image]

Why do I have this error in my R code?

Comment: Please copy-paste code and errors into your question as formatted text. It is difficult to debug as an image and consequently, many people will ignore your question.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps confusingly, [`geom_raster()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggplot2/versions/0.9.0/topics/geom_raster) does not take a `raster` as input but rather a `dataframe`.

Try:

```r
# convert your raster object to a dataframe
malaysia2019_df <- raster::as.data.frame(malaysia2019, xy=TRUE)  

# plot the dataframe 
ggplot() +
  geom_raster(data=malaysia2019_df,  # use the dataframe rather than the raster
              aes(x=x,
                  y=y, 
                  fill=column_name_you_wish_to_plot  # change the `fill` to the column name of the data you wish to plot
              )
  )
```